# The new <SaveContextProvider>, deprecated-message of React-Admin

Tags: react-admin

I have this message in the Chrome console since I updated react-admin to version 3.10.0, I tried to dig into the document but can't find any information or example. Anyone encounter this, or luckily any members of react-admin seeing this, please help!

```
Edit or Create child components must be used inside a <SaveContextProvider>. Relying on props rather than context to get persistence related data and callbacks is deprecated and won't be supported in the next major version of react-admin.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a form component, using `<SimpleForm>`, that is used in `<Edit>` and `<Create>` components. There is no warnings when app is running.

But I have the same issue when unit tests are running on the form component. I tried to wrap it inside a `<SaveContextProvider>` without success... if someone have solution !

So if you encounter the issue during runtime you should verify that your form component is well wrapped as mentioned in the warning.